Dark mode works automatically for all pages except Firefox
In Firefox (and its forks) that dark mode doesn't apply to all pages automatically. If you select dark mode it only works on one page, you have to set it manually on each page. In other browsers (Brave, Opera, etc), if you set the dark mode once, all the pages will be in dark mode automatically.
Why doesn't this code work properly in Firefox? Local storage doesn't work on it? Will I have to use cookie instead?
let trilho = document.getElementById('trilho');
let body = document.querySelector('body');

// Check local storage for the user's theme preference
const theme = window.localStorage.getItem("theme");

// Set the initial theme based on localStorage
if (theme === "dark") {
    body.classList.add("dark");
    trilho.classList.add("dark"); // Ensure the button reflects dark mode
} else {
    trilho.classList.remove("dark"); // Ensure the button reflects light mode
}

// Add event listener to toggle dark mode
trilho.addEventListener('click', () => {
    trilho.classList.toggle('dark');
    body.classList.toggle('dark');

    // Update localStorage with the current theme
    if (body.classList.contains("dark")) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
        trilho.classList.add("dark"); // Dark mode button
    } else {
        window.localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
        trilho.classList.remove("dark"); // Light mode button
    }
});


What's the difference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79145027/how-do-i-apply-dark-mode-to-all-the-websites-pages-via-localstorage

Jaba, the difference is that, for some reason, someone was downvoting my question, and then it appeared blocked, then deleted. I don't even know what I did wrong.

Why do you expect, that this question won't be downvoted, closed and deleted, too?

So I tried to ask again, but someone's already downvoted it and they'll probably block my question again, I don't know why.

When people tried your code it worked, so there's not enough information to tell why it doesn't work for you. Reposting the exact same thing is not likely to produce any better results.

Barmar, I only posted the JS, how could someone just test my code with that without the rest of the css and html?
I'm saying it's not working, so it's not. But someone said that my code was saving the user's preference, but not applying it, so I think that's the problem. But I don't know how to apply it, that's why I'm asking.

Other users tested your code and it works. If you have a problem, it's in the code you haven't posted. How could anybody help you if you don't provide necessary details?

Jabaa, They haven't tested it because they don't have the full code (css and html). Maybe by looking at the code they'll see that saving the user's preference is working, and it is, some guy just helped me to do this code and it's perfect! But that's not the problem.
I'm specifying that the user's preference is being saved, so if you refresh the page it's saved in dark mode, but that doesn't automatically apply to other pages. It's necessary for the user to choose dark or light mode manually on each page, so I'm asking how I can make the mode choice automatic, working for all pages.

I assume, they filled the gaps and added the missing code. That means, the posted code is correct. The problem is in the missing code. Please provide a [mcve].

I can't post the whole code because I keep getting the error ‘It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
I'd like to describe it further, to give more details, but this error won't go away. I don't know what to do.

Don't post the whole code. Create and post a [mcve]. You should either trilho.classList.toggle('dark'); or trilho.classList.add("dark"); and trilho.classList.remove("dark");

Jabba, i managed to update the post and add the code. I've almost completely added the dark mode code. What's missing in the css is the code for each color, like:
body.dark .container {
background-color: #000;
}
missing for:
body.dark footer {
body.dark header {
body.dark h1 {
body.dark a {
body.dark form{
body.dark .rodape{

I tested it in the Brave browser, and it worked on all pages. I tested it in Edge and it also worked. So apparently the problem was with my Firefox browser. In Firefox it doesn't work for all pages automatically.

The next step is to debug the problem. Run the code in your debugger and check the values. Check the DOM. What exactly doesn't work in Firefox? Do you see error messages in the console?

The code is perfect then, saving and applying the user's choice, the problem was the browser. I tried another browser, a fork of Firefox, and it didn't work either. So the problem is in Firefox, I just don't know how to solve it lol

Jabaa, what's not working in Firefox is that dark mode doesn't apply to all pages automatically. If you select dark mode it only works on one page, you have to set it manually on each one. In other browsers, if you set the dark mode, all the pages are in dark mode automatically.

What exactly doesn't work? Is it a problem with local storage? Is the value read when you step through the code using the debugger? Is the DOM modified correctly? Are the CSS classes set? Is the CSS style loaded? Don't dump your code and write "it doesn't work". That's not how this platform works. Debug the problem and ask specific questions about behavior you don't understand. Do you see error messages in the console or network monitor?

Jabaa, I've updated my post and explained it better now that I've discovered the real problem.

Do you see errors in the console or network monitor? Does the JavaScript code work as expected when you step line by line through it with your debugger? Do you see the changes in the DOM when you analyze it in the dev tools? Do you see the expected value in the local storage in the dev tools? Do you see the expected CSS styles when you analyze the DOM elements in the dev tools?

According to the [tour], "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers." Programmers write and debug code. This is not a job platform. Currently, it seems like you're looking for a programmer on this platform. Someone else wrote the posted code for you and now you want someone else to debug the code for you.

@Kay8 The proper way to handle dark mode is through CSS. Users should set their dark mode preferences in the browser. This provides users the most consistent experience.
Example:
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .theme-a.adaptive {
    background: #753;
    color: #dcb;
    outline: 5px dashed #000;
  }
}

